# Using getline with cin

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to store space separated strings with `cin`, and I learned that I have tot use `getline`. But if there is another `cin` before `getline cin`, second `cin` is not read.

Here is example:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int ID;
    string Artist;

    cout << "Enter ID:\n";
    cin >> ID;
    cout << ID << " this is ID\n";

    cout << "Enter Artist name:\n";
    std::getline(cin, Artist);
    cout << Artist << " this is Artist\n";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Artist is not prompted for entry, and assigned "". How to fix that?

Comment: Not a duplicate, I cannot use getline with int

Comment: The duplicate exactly explains what's going wrong with your code. The type doesn't matter.